# How to exclude certain HTTP requests from being logged in Java Spring (e.g. /health Endpoint)

Tags: java, spring, logging, filter, spring-boot-actuator

In my Spring boot application the following setting:

```
logging.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

causes all HTTP requests to be logged, which is cool!

However, as the /health endpoint is continuously polled, this spams the logfile.
How can I disable request logging just for this endpoint?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but a log level of DEBUG will always be spammy.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use Spring Built-In request logging filter `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`.

To enable the logging filter, you need to set the property:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

But when you need specify custom rules for enabling logging, you can create custom implementation in following way:

```
@Component
public class RequestLoggingFilter extends AbstractRequestLoggingFilter {

    private Set<String> excludedUrls = Set.of("/health");

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldLog(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(excludedUrls.contains(request.getRequestURI())) {
            return false;
        }
        return logger.isDebugEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
        logger.debug(message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
        logger.debug(message);
    }
}
```

and to enable the filter add the following config property to `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.<package_name>.RequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive answer including sample code!!!
This seems to remove the log lines "Before request" and "After request".
However, a lot is logged when AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal calls filterChain.doFilter. This part is still logged.

Comment: (6 lines in trace mode, 4 lines in debug mode).

Comment: My answer is like example, you can define your own filter which will be not extended from AbstractRequestLoggingFilter or you can override methods for correct logging, but the main idea of logging requests should be based on filters.